# Why is the geometry of tetracyanonickelate(II) square planar? Why is it colorless?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, color

Why is the geometry of $\ce{[Ni(CN)4)]^2-}$ square planar given that it has a coordination number of 4?  Shouldn't its geometry be tetrahedral as it would minimise the bond angle and hence repulsion?

Also, why is it colorless? I saw that it is related to how $\ce{CN^-}$ is a relatively strong field ligand and can cause “pairing” of the electrons which would not allow the electrons to be transferred between d-orbitals, but what does it mean by pairing?

Comment: Because it has two lone pairs?

Comment: This has nothing to do with lone pairs... I think, you can start by reading my answer here: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/40881/16683 If you have any questions, tell me.

Comment: that is a comparison between two different metal centres so does not answer this specific question.

Comment: @gamma1 Nowhere did I claim that it answered this specific question. However, the factors that affect the adoption of a square planar geometry vs tetrahedral geometry are the same, regardless of whether it is the metal centre or the ligand that is being compared. Hence, I felt it was related, but of course not a duplicate for the reason you mentioned. If you want to, you're more than welcome to write up an answer that actually compares the ligands.