# Number of unpaired electron and total spin angular moment

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions, transition-metals

IIT-JEE advanced 2013 has a question:

> Give the correct order of the complex ions given below according to their spin-only magnetic moment:
>   A. $\ce{[FeF6]^{3-}}$
>   B. $\ce{[V(H2O)6]^{2+}}$
>   C. $\ce{[Fe(H2O)6]^{2+}}$

So, my reasoning is more unpaired electron results in greater spin-only magnetic moment. So, the order should be B>A>C

But the answer is given A>C>B.

I don't know where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first choice lists $\ce{Fe^3+}$ as the central metal atom (CMA), so you have the configuration: $\mathrm{3d^5 4s^0}$. Remember that fluoride is a weak field ligand and would not cause pairing of electrons. This gives you 5 unpaired electrons.

The second choice has $\ce{V^2+}$ as the CMA, the configuration being $\mathrm{3d^3 4s^0}$. This gives you 3 unpaired electrons.

Finally, the third choice has $\ce{Fe^2+}$ as the CMA. Yet again water is a weak field ligand and does not cause pairing of electrons. The isolated configuration although is $\mathrm{3d^6 4s^0}$, but now you'd have 4 electrons in the $\mathrm{t_2g}$ set and 2 electrons in the $\mathrm{e_g}$ set. So now you've 4 unpaired electrons.

> more unpaired electron results in greater spin-only magnetic moment.

This is true and I can see it being followed as $\mathrm{A>C>B}$.

---

Also see [my comment for the strength of ligands](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73017/hybridisation-of-complex-compound-having-octahedral-geometry/73027#comment127917_73027).

Answer (score 1):

The answer A>C>B is correct. I think you might have considered Fluoride to be a strong field ligand but it's actually not that strong so there won't be any pairing in the first compound as a result it will have five unpaired electrons. The remaining compounds have lesser unpaired electrons so yeah the order is justified.